# Creating a plotly express image with custom image ratio

Tags: plotly, image-size

I'm trying to build a very simple plot in `plotly` express with custom dimensions but cannot get the result I want.

My image is an array with dimensions 300 and 5000, I want it to be stretched into a smaller dimension, such that it looks big on a screen.

It is super easy to do in `matplotlib`, but I get weird results in `plotly`. This is what I have using `matplotlib`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80)
image = np.random.random([300, 5000])
plt.imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray_r', aspect='auto')
```

[image: plot created by matplotlib]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is what you currently have:

```py
# Missing imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Your code from the question
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80)
# Smaller array to speed things up
image = np.random.random([30, 500])
plt.imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="gray_r", aspect="auto")
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

Now you want to use plotly. You can plot the same image with the default settings:

```py
# Plotly default
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(image)
fig.show()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

To get the same colour and aspect ratio you need to add some arguments to [`px.imshow`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.imshow.html). Note that here the width and height are in pixels, so you need to convert your (20, 10) numbers accordingly using the dpi of 80.

```py
# Plotly to match matplotlib
fig = px.imshow(image, color_continuous_scale="gray_r", aspect="auto", width=1600, height=800)
fig.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: The problem now is that plotly express is very slow with an array size of (300,5000). I added binary_string=True option to speed things up and it the figure size goes back to the the same size as in your colored image. Seams like binary_string option overwrites width/height and aspect options. Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Yes, as plotly is interactive it sends the data to the browser. Large plots become slow. If you want to keep the interactivity and use large datasets you could perhaps look into [holoviews datashader](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html). Regarding why binary_string overrides the width/height: I don't know. What have *you* looked into so far?

Comment: I'm looking into datashader right now although my dataset is not big, I hope to get smth that responds better

Comment: If you don't have big datasets datashader is not worth it, as it involves running an engine in the background that aggregates points on the fly.  I'm not sure why you want to use plotly, but if it's only for the interactivity you could also look into the [options that matplotlib offers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html#interactive-mode).

Comment: I need plotly for my dash plotly app. Dash plotly does not support matplotlib images. It gave me an error when I tried to use a figure created by matplotlib imshow inside the plotly dcc.Graph.

Comment: Did you search on how to use a matplotlib image in dash? https://community.plotly.com/t/best-way-to-incorporate-matplotlib-plot-in-dash-app/12896