# plotly.express.imshow aspect ratio issue

Tags: python, plotly

The horizontal axis of the data is much larger than the vertical axis.
As a result, plotly shows weird aspect ratio.

Here is the current code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb['2']

data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append([0] * 433)
x = [i + 1 for i in range(433)]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# vertical-axis : 10, horizontal-axis : 433

for item in ws:
    data[item[2].value][item[3].value - 1] += 1

fig = px.imshow(data, x=x, y=y)

fig.show()
```

And here is the result:

zoomed out-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcHX6.png)

zoomed in-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFaFI.png)

I inserted the parameter that width and height

As a result, I expected it changes the aspect ratio but doesn't show anything all

Comment: Hello, does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72808206/12846804